# what is yaml file in java and use of it?

Tags: java, yaml, javafx-2

i saw some site like this http://jyaml.sourceforge.net/ for yaml in java.

but i can't to use of that.

how can i use form yaml files?

if is it possible to use it in javafx 2.0?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**What is YAML**
You should see [the Wikipedia page for YAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaml) at least. The [official YAML website](http://yaml.org/) defines it as

> [...] a human friendly data serialization
>     standard for all programming languages.

---

**Use with Java**
It depends on what you want to use it for - the most common use (I'd imagine, since I haven't used it myself) would be for storing application configuration, as an alternative to XML or JSON. Essentially, you'll have a simple text file that contains data in a structured format as defined by the YAML spec. Here is [an article that discusses the use of YAML with Java](http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/38509).

To avoid reinventing the wheel, you should make use of a library that performs the serialization and deserialization for you i.e. it can read from and write to the text file and parse the data in it and hand it over to your application in an easier to use object form. The business logic, of course, must be written by you. There are several Java libraries that are available and this question on SO talks about which one to use and why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450399/which-java-yaml-library-should-i-use.

Comment: I don't see why not - it's a language independent data format and there are libraries for Java. Why do you think you can't make use of it in your Java app? And what do you want to use it for?

Comment: @no.good.at.coding I think he want more about thrid part libraries/dependiences useage - not about yaml itself - tangled

Comment: can you introduce a web address to me for attaching a yaml file to my application.

Comment: @mehdi I'm terribly confused about **what you're trying to do with YAML, if you understand what it is/does and what it is that you're asking exactly**. It is simply a data serialization format - you can have a plain text file that stores some structured data that your application can use. It's just a file that you can read from and write to. But you don't want to reinvent the wheel so you make use of existing libraries that perform serialization and deserialization for you. Any business logic must be written by you.

Comment: @mehdi I've linked to an article that discusses the use of YAML in Java applications, does that help?

Comment: @inquisitor Thanks for that. I'm still not sure, though, what the question is about!

Answer (score 0):

Yaml is a file format<sup>*</sup>, and jYaml  is a Java library for working with that file format.

So you may use it to read or write information into this format.

> How can i use form yaml files?

You write one, and use it with this library.

> If is it possible to use it in javafx 2.0?

Can you use this library in JavaFX 2.0?  If you can then yes. :)

<sup>*</sup> See comment

Comment: According to the site (and Wikipedia), they've backronymed it to `YAML Ain't Markup Language` :)